# Не ловит пакеты udp broadcast при общении между сервером и клиентом

Tags: c++, linux, сокет, sfml

У меня есть небольшой сетевой код на c++ с использованием SFML 2.6 для одноразовой передачи пакетов в локальной сети. Однако, одно из устройств(ноутбук с linux mint), не получает пакеты от другого устройства(ПК с windows 10), если они отправлены в broadcast по айпи 255.255.255.255(его дал sf::IpAddress::Broadcast). Однако если ноутбук передает пакет, то он почти сразу приходит на ПК. При этом tcp-протокол работает корректно в обе стороны.

Сервер(линукс):

```
#include <SFML/Network.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    sf::UdpSocket socket;
    socket.bind(6885);
    std::cout << sf::IpAddress::getLocalAddress() << std::endl;

    char data[128];
    std::size_t received;
    sf::IpAddress remote;
    unsigned short port;
    socket.receive(data, 128, received, remote, port); //Не работает, если отправлено через broadcasting(на линуксе)
    std::cout << data[0];
    

    return 0;
}
```

Клиент(виндовс)

```
#include <SFML/Network.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    sf::UdpSocket socket;
    socket.bind(sf::Socket::AnyPort);
    unsigned short port = 6885;

    std::string data = "Hello, Server";
    socket.send(data.c_str(), data.size() + 1, sf::IpAddress::IpAddress("192.168.100.148"), port); //Работает корректно на обоих устройствах
    //socket.send(data.c_str(), data.size() + 1, sf::IpAddress::Broadcast, port); //Работает только если ноутбук отправляет ПК


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: вы не проверяете успешность `if(socket.receive(data, 128, received, remote, port) == sf::Socket::Done){ ok }else{ not_ok }` и выводите на экран только одну букву `std::cout << data[0];` каким способом вы так решаете, что сигнал пришёл успешно таким образом? Так-же протокол UDP не гарантирует доставку. Надо посылать раз в секунду. Всё зависит от архитектуры вашей сети. Может быть роутер гасит ваш сигнал Broadcast.

Comment: Если данные отправляет ноутбук, то код на ПК их спокойно ловит(в отличии от обратной ситуации). И, к сожалению, выражение if else ничем не помогает, т.к receive дожидается сообщения, которого нет

Comment: у `send` тоже надо проверить успешность `== sf::Socket::Done`. Чтобы точно всё узнать.

Comment: С send в клиенте все хорошо, судя по sf::Socket::Done

Comment: в инете говорят виндовс сбрасывает upd ...255 И вам надо в винде эту блокировку отключить.  Находится где-то в сетевое подключение--дополнительные настройки-.. *винда очень много блокирует. для начала просто отключите firewall и посмотрите.*

Comment: Не-а, это тоже не помогло от слова совсем

Comment: 80% что дело в вайфае